# On the Diophantine equation $x^{p-1} + py^{p-1} = z^{p-1}$

Tags: number-theory

One day I stumbled across a number theory problem that states:

> Given a prime $p > 5$, prove that if $(x,y,z)$ is an integer solution to the equation
> $$x^{p-1} + py^{p-1} = z^{p-1}$$
> then we must have $y=0$.

As far as I know, with $p=3$ we have $(x,y,z) = (1,1,2)$ and with $p=5$ we have $(x,y,z) = (1,2,3)$. But with $p=7$ and $11$, using brute force I found no solutions where $y\ne 0$ so I wonder whether the problem is true for every $p>5$ or not. (Edit: Yes, it is true for all $p>5$)

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E%7Bp-1%7D%20%2B%20py%5E%7Bp-1%7D%20%3D%20z%5E%7Bp-1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), I found the AoPS thread [Number theory problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1344377p7314069), as well as [Number Theory LTE?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1713866p11063705) but which currently has no results in it.

Comment: Indeed, you should edit it as: "Given a prime $p>5$, prove that if $(x,y,z)$..."  This is a generalised Fermat equation with "Euler characteristic" $\frac{3}{p-1}<1$, so the hyperbolic case. See [here](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/Fermatlectures.pdf).